# Merge Sort Algorithm merging of two a arrays in third on a condition

Tags: c++

this a algorithm of merging two arrays on a certain condition. it first compare the index of two arrays and if the index of an arrayP1 is equal to index of arrayp2 the it will store that certain index into the answer array.
can any one help to translate this algorithm in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
 { 

int sizeofarray=0,i=0 ,j=0, num=0, answers[]={};
cout<<"enter the size of array"<<endl;
cin>>sizeofarray;//take size of array from user
int array1[sizeofarray];
int array2[sizeofarray];
cout<<"please enter a sorted array member of Array1"<<endl;
//input of array element 
for ( i=0 ; i<=sizeofarray; i++)
{
cin>>array1[i];
}
system("CLS");
cout<<"please enter a sorted array member of Array2"<<endl;
for (j=0 ; j<=sizeofarray; j++)
{
cin>>array2[j];
}
 ***strong text***system("CLS");
//comparing the array element and storing the similar items to another         array
while(array1[i]!=NULL && array2[j]!=NULL){
if(array1[i]==array2[j]){
answer[num++]=array1[i];
i++;
j++;
}
else if(array1[i]<array2[j])
{
i++;
}else{
  j++;
   }
 i++;
 j++;
 }
 cout<<"The number of common elements"<<num<<endl;
 cout<<"These are the common numbers: ";
 for (int k=0;k<num;k++){
cout<<answer[k]<<" ";
 }
 getch();
 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Someone probably can.

Comment: I think so too, doesn't look that hard. What have you tried so far? Include your code

Comment: That is not merging but intersecting 2 sorted sets. Your headline is misleading.

Comment: @qadeer  It is not an algorithm of merging two arrays.  It is an algorithm of intersection.:)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I have edited the question and also have posted my effort in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int sizeofarray=0,i=0 ,j=0, num=0, answers[]={};
cout<<"enter the size of array"<<endl;
cin>>sizeofarray;//take size of array from user
int array1[sizeofarray];
int array2[sizeofarray];
cout<<"please enter a sorted array member of Array1"<<endl;
//input of array element 
for ( i=0 ; i<=sizeofarray; i++)
{
    cin>>array1[i];
}
system("CLS");
cout<<"please enter a sorted array member of Array2"<<endl;
for (j=0 ; j<=sizeofarray; j++)
{
    cin>>array2[j];
}
system("CLS");
//comparing the array element and storing the similar items to another array
while(array1[i]!=NULL && array2[j]!=NULL){
    if(array1[i]==array2[j]){
    answer[num++]=array1[i];
    i++;
    j++;
    }
    else if(array1[i]<array2[j])
{
i++;
}else{
j++;
    }
i++;
j++;
}
cout<<"The number of common elements"<<num<<endl;
cout<<"These are the common numbers: ";
for (int k=0;k<num;k++){
    cout<<answer[k]<<" ";
}
getch();
return 0;

}
```